# Pipe sed capture group through external program before replacing?

Tags: regex, sed, find-and-replace, capture-group

Is there a way for `sed` to pipe a capture group to another program,  making `\1` in the regexp's RHS equal to the output of that program?

For example, running

```
sed 's/lorem ipsum \(foobar\)/\1/g' file.txt
```

would pipe "foobar" through another program (e.g., `tr 'o' 'a'`) to make `\1` be "faabar" for `sed` to replace "lorem ipsum foobar" with "lorem ipsum faabar"?

<sup>This is just a simple example. I realize I could convert "foobar" to "faabar" without using `tr`.</sup>

Comment: Is a perl one-liner an option for you? `perl -ape 's/(?:lorem ipsum (?=\bfoobar\b)|\G)[^o\s]*\Ko/a/g' file.txt`

Comment: Another: `perl -ape 's/lorem ipsum \K\bfoobar\b/{($x=$&)=~s|o|a|g;$x}/e' file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `sed` is GNU `sed`. you can use `s/…/…/e`.

> `e`
>   This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed extension.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command))</sup>

Note it executes the *entire* pattern space and replaces the *entire* pattern space. Usually it's the entire line. You want to manipulate a fragment: `foobar`. Either you find a way to manipulate the pattern space so at some moment it holds only `foobar`, without missing anything before or after `foobar` at the end of the line processing; or you actually prepare the entire line to be executed in a shell. I cannot easily do the former but I think I can do the latter.

You need to:

1. Change every `'` to `'"'"'` so code injection is not possible later.
2. Inject `'"$(printf … | external_command …)"'` in the right place(s).
3. Embrace the entire line in `printf '%s' '` and `'`.
4. Execute the line

At each step you should take possible results of previous steps into consideration. E.g. if your pattern was not `foobar` but `foo'bar`, then after the first step you should seek for `foo'"'"'bar` (with proper escaping if needed).

When written properly, the procedure may be applied to every line. To reduce the number of spawned shells and `external_command`s you can do this only for lines that really need it.

To solve your example:

```
sed "/lorem ipsum foobar/ {
   s#'#'\"'\"'#g
   s#\(lorem ipsum \)\(foobar\)#\1'\"\$(printf '%s' '\2' | tr 'o' 'a')\"'#g
   s#.*#printf '%s' '\0'#e
}"
```

Note the entire script is double-quoted; characters like `"` and `$` are escaped because of this.

Answer (score 1):

A NATURAL attempt would be to change:

> sed 's/lorem ipsum (foobar)/\1/g' file.txt

Into:

> sed -re "s/lorem ipsum (foobar)/$(echo "-\1-" | tr 'o' 'a')/g" file.txt

Expected effect:
The content held in `\1` gets piped into `tr` which modifies and prints it, to be caught by `$(...)` which then is used by sed... trick done, hmm?

Well what happens is that `$(...)` runs BEFORE sed is launched, i.e.
`echo "-\1-" | tr 'o' 'a'` - with the end effect the same as from:

> sed -re "s/lorem ipsum (foobar)/-\1-)/g" file.txt

so, this does not work.

**Suggested method:**
Use a short python script, `import re` to use regular expressions similar to above, with additional code to replace it in the way you wish.

Comment: updated to explain the problem, not an answer sadly.